# What is the name of this artifact where lines appear in what should be a smooth gradient?

Tags: terminology, artifacts

I'm very new in the world of photography, and I want to know the name of this problem.

[image]

I know there is a word and I searched but I could not find it.
If someone knows the word then please enlighten me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's *color banding*. It can be caused by *posterization* due to insufficient bit depth for smooth gradations in a small color range ­— or can be a common artifact of JPEG compression.

Comment: While 95% of the things on this site that people mistake for color banding is not color banding, *this* really is (and is a clearer example than in the linked duplicate)!